# SELECT all contacts in table that do NOT have "X"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select CONTACTS in my MySQL table, that does NOT have any associated information in the INVESTMENTS table.

I have a query that is something like this, but it's not pulling all my contacts properly.

**TL;DR Select ALL contacts, then remove all contacts that have investments**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    contacts
INNER JOIN investments ON investments.contactId = contacts.contactId
WHERE
    contacts.userId = '1'
    AND contacts.trash IS NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM investments WHERE investments.company IS NULL )
GROUP BY
    contacts.contactId
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here check out this fiddle, I was going to add an answer but well they closed it.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nucna7J1LTX1gMVwiuw1Mf/3

Comment: Thank you for your input! This was great.

Comment: Sure, Like I said I would have put an answer but it was closed, see you around!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `inner join` requires a matching entry in the joined table. What you need to find *non-matching entries* is an `outer join`, and a simple where condition on a joined table’s field being `null`.

`Outer Join`s make up a ‘dummy record’ with all NULL values for the joined table where no match can be found.. for example, if you have table 1 with a, b, c in the only column, and you `outer join` with table 2 which contains a-1, b-2, you would get a match for the first two entries of table 1, and no match -> dummy record for the 3rd value: a-a-1, b-b-2, c-NULL-NULL. Now you can control what of the result you want to see by adding `where` conditions, like `where table2-col is null`, and only the third match remains - c-NULL-NULL.

Note that their are `left outer join`s and `right outer join`s, depending if you want the dummies created for unmatched entries of the left or the right table. Sql allows to drop the word `outer`, so it often reads `left join` and `right join`

Comment: Possible to clarify a little? I'm not entirely familiar with OUTER Joins.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/6521550 Inner Join vs outer Join

Comment: You can drop the `inner` and just use `JOIN`.  thought I should mention that.

Comment: Thanks Aganju, yes that makes sense now. Frustrating how I was using something simple and just a brain fart i suppose not thinking about the outer join. Was thinking totally wrong initially. Appreciate the help on this! Thanks.!

Comment: I don't see much in the way of actual SQL, nice explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using a `LEFT JOIN` and checking if the company IS NULL. By using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` you still get the `contacts` that don't have anything in the `investments` table.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    contacts
LEFT JOIN investments ON investments.contactId = contacts.contactId
WHERE
    contacts.userId = '1'
    AND contacts.trash IS NULL
    AND investments.company IS NULL
GROUP BY
    contacts.contactId
```

Comment: Yeah, frustrating mistake, i was thinking entirely different. The LEFT join makes a world of a difference obviously. So this makes sense. Same as Aganju mentioned.   Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

SELECT  * FROM contacts c

LEFT JOIN investments i ON i.contactId = c.contactId

WHERE  c.userId = '1'  AND c.trash IS NULL   AND i.company IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY   c.contactId